# How to do the equivalent of a "where" clause with `find` and `grep`

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have a folder tree of text files and I would like to find instances of a substring and the names of the files they came from.

If I do something like:

```
find . | xargs cat | grep 'abc'
```

then I would find instances of the substring, but not the files they originally came from.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: just use `grep -r`, or `grep -rl` which are supported on Linux, *BSD, and Solaris (via `ggrep`).

Comment: @mosvy as I read it the OP wants both the filename and the matching line. `-l` only gives the filename...

Comment: @xenoid that's why I had written "`grep -r` or `grep -rl`"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running `xargs cat` like that loses the filenames and there's no good way to pass them through the pipeline at the same time as the data flows through.

But `grep -l` lists the names of files with matching strings, so you could use that:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l hello
```

Or with just having `grep -r` recursively dig through the directory, also resolving issues the issues `xargs` has with filenames containing white space or quotes:

```
grep -lre abc .
```

If you wanted the matching strings too, and not just the filenames, remove the `-l` to get the usual `grep` behaviour. With `-r`, it should print the matching filenames too even though we only give one path on the command line.

Comment: what about spaces in filenames?

Comment: @mosvy, that's what "odd filenames" was supposed to mean, sorry for the lax phrasing

Comment: I am surprised that the OP accepted this answer, because the question says “I would like to ***find instances of a substring*** and the names of the files they came from”, but this shows *only* the filenames and not the ‘‘instances’’.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' so.. removing the `-l` will work. I'd add `-H` if the filename wasn't showing.

Comment: It so happens in my use case there aren't going to be multiple instance _per file_, so this was the most helpful answer to me, YMMV. Thanks to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 7):

`xargs` is superfluous. When you do `xargs cat | grep`, `grep` only sees a nameless input stream that contains the concatenated content of all the files. Do instead:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -H 'abc' {} +
```

This will call `grep` on each file (and minimizes the number of instances of `grep`, by calling `grep` with several files as parameters).

Comment: If you're using GNU grep (because of the `-H` flag), you might just as well dispense with `find` and use `grep -r`. But if you have to use find (eg. to filter files by mtime), I think you can make that portable with `find . -type f -exec grep 'abc' /dev/null {} +`

Comment: @mosvy Yes, the `-H` is to catch the possible singleton in the last `grep` call that would make grep not report the file name. The `/dev/null` trick is cool but it could baffle someone inheriting the script, so it's `-H` or a line of comment...

Comment: `-H` is not standard. And script inheritors are easily baffled by pretty much everything, I don't think that makes any difference ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
find ./ -type f -exec grep -H abc {} \;
```

or

```bsh
grep -R 'abc' ./
```

Comment: [ditto](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/575312/how-to-do-the-equivalent-of-a-where-clause-with-find-and-grep#comment1071377_575319)

Comment: My answer has been added.
 At 12:07:51 against 12:10:18

Comment: Your answer is different, because it's using `-exec ... \;` instead of `-exec ... +` and so it will spawn a separate grep process for each file, instead of handling the files in batches of ~ > 1k files to grep. But my point was that `-H` is NOT a portable option of grep, and grep implementations which support `-H` also support `-r` or `-R`.

Comment: But yes, all the answers to this Q are pretty lousy, yours is not particular in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Try `awk` instead of `cat`  and `grep`

```
find . -type f | xargs awk '/abc/{printf "%s is from %s\n", $0, FILENAME}'
```

Or just use `find` and `awk`

```
find . -type f -exec awk '/abc/{printf "%s is from %s\n", $0, FILENAME}' {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

Grep takes multiple filenames and reads the files, and with multiple args it shows the filenames, so just pass the filename list direct.

Also, don't pass directories to grep. And use null-terminated filenames to avoid special characters in filenames.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep 'abc'
```